# What is basic reason behind creating objects in the powerful programming languages

Tags: object

what is the basic need of creating object in the programming language i have come acrossed almost 3-4 programming languages which posses the feature of object creating. Following are the languages :-
1.C++
2.java 
3.php
4.JS
my question is that what was that root need that the programmers built the concept of the object was bought into the focus and practiced and after that what magic happened that now almost all powerful programming language support this function of object

Comment: A starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 4):

Conclusion from: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

The object-oriented approach is in reality a logical extension of good design practices

It's simply the logical extension of older techniques such as structured programming and abstract data types.

The new technique was also hyped a lot and commercialized to 'sell' a programming language. (Hence most major languages have the concept, and it was implemented in some older languages because of this.)

Comment: see demian i am a straight forward guy ok so o like to play by the rules and stick to the fundamentals i just dont want to skip anything because Later it can be a pain in the neck

Comment: I first learned to program in a procedural way, only two months later we had our first 'object-oriented' experience. It was intended like this to let us learn the basics first. (variables, assignments, operators, methods and parameters...)

Comment: i guess starting from scratch in a simple way is the most strongest way to learn the most complex things in the world you understand the working of a nuclear reactor but for that first you have to understand the process of fission,fusion,cooling etc am i right i think i am pretty much